# Need alternative way to delete a <li> element in a <ul> list in CSS. (Not HTML)

Tags: html, css, list, image

I have to design a mock-up website using CSS codes.

The mock-up website: https://tasksheet.tempurl.host/

Here is the particular list
[image]

The expected result
[image]

I deleted the last to li element using HTML codes

1. li class="wp-block-post post-31 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized" style="display: none;"
2. li class="wp-block-post post-33 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized" style="display: none;"

Issue:
While I have achieved the expected target, I could not find an alternative way to delete the last two li list elements within a ul list using CSS. I could not find any alternative method to achieve this expected result. So could anybody give me some advice or suggestions or help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete elements with CSS, you just make them invisible. To really delete them you need JS or you have to edit the HTML.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).